# How to have the value of the selected in radioButtonList

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" CssClass="status_Veh">
        <asp:ListItem ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" name="status"   Selected="True" Value="New">New</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" name="status"    Value="Used" >Used</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</html>
```

need to have the selected value of the radio buttonList using Jquery

I'm using

`var statusVeh = $(".status_Veh option:selected ").val();`

it isn't working

nor is

`var statusVeh = $(".status_Veh:checked").val();`

Comment: It might help if you posted what the markup looks like after the server renders it...

Answer (score 2):

Try `$(".status_Veh input:checked").val();`

RadioButtonList generates , so the option:selected selector won't work.

$(".status_Veh:checked").val() is not working, because you have to look the .status_Veh elements children for checked values. So $(".status_Veh :checked").val() should also work (notice the space in the selector).

Comment: There was a typo. Try $(".status_Veh input:checked").val()

Answer (score 2):

you can try `$('input[name=status]:checked').val()`